# MDC 101 Material Design Tutorial throwing error when npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I m getting loads of errors when i run `npm install` (I m using mac Catalina).

```
starter npm install

> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v83-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@14.15.3 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2722:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in
      'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: 
      expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2722:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:127:26: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in
      'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: 
      expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2818:
../../nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h:34:43: warning: 'GetContents' is deprecated: Use
      GetBackingStore. See http://crbug.com/v8/9908. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      data   = static_cast<char*>(buffer->GetContents().Data()) + byte_offset;
                                          ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:5272:3: note: 
      'GetContents' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON("Use GetBackingStore. See http://crbug.com/v8/9908.")
  ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8config.h:402:39: note: 
      expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
# define V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
                                      ^
../fsevents.cc:43:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:89:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone").ToLocalChecked()...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:90:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs").ToLoc...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:91:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:92:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped").ToLocal...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~


                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:93:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped").ToLoc...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^

In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:94:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:95:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:96:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagMount").ToLocalChecked(...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:97:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagUnmount").ToLocalChecke...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:98:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:99:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:100:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemInodeMetaMod").ToLo...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:101:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed").ToLocalCh...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:102:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified").ToLocalC...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:103:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod").ToL...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:104:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner").ToLoc...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v83-darwin-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)

> fibers@4.0.1 install /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:899:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
                        target->Set(sym_yield, yield);
                        ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3673:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
../src/fibers.cc:903:8: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
                        fn->Set(sym_yield, yield);
                        ~~~~^~~
/Users/gayan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.15.3/include/node/v8.h:3670:37: note: candidate
      function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided

                                          ^
../src/fibers.cc:206:25: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
                info.GetReturnValue().Set(handle);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
../src/fibers.cc:838:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'uni::Return<v8::Object>' requested here
                                return uni::Return(current->handle, info);

                 ^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
sh: nodejs: command not found
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! fibers@4.0.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    
➜  starter
```

Then I tried the following code

```
npm i fsevents@latest -f --save-optional
```

and try to start the server using`npm start`

Then i hit the following error

```
    ➜  starter npm start

> mdc-101-web@0.0.0 start /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter
> webpack-dev-server --progress

## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-83/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web\ Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/build
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-83/fibers'
Require stack:
- /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js
- /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/webpack.config.js
- /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js
- /Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:14:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:23
        throw new Error('Missing binary. See message above.');
        ^

Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:23:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at getStyleUse (/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/webpack.config.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gayan/Desktop/Web Development/material-components-web-codelabs-master/mdc-101/starter/webpack.config.js:32:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mdc-101-web@0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mdc-101-web@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gayan/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T14_20_40_046Z-debug.log
```

Then I tried the following

```
npm uninstall fibers
npm install fibers
npm install
```

after that my server started successfully

However i do not understand why this error was coming.

Can anyone help me why the tutorial in the following link does not work and why the those errors occurs

Thanks in advance.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web#1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - the package versions in package-lock.json were not matching my setup (node version etc.), so after deleting package-lock.json, the installation went well without any errors and the application started running also without errors.

Comment: how did you get it to reinstall smoothly, for me it regenerates package-lock.json every time

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, but my error was

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/chad/code/material-components-web-codelabs/mdc-101/starter/node_modules/fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.5.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
...
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/fibers.cc:899:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
npm ERR!                         target->Set(sym_yield, yield);
npm ERR!                         ~~~~~~~~^~~
```

I tried what the original poster mentioned above, but still had issues.
It turns out fibers is not supported on node >= 16.0.0 as stated in their readme https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers

> Update [April 13th, 2021] -- Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later. Unfortunately, v8 commit dacc2fee0f is a breaking change and workarounds are non-trivial.

I ended up using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to set the node version to 14. After starting the installation over, I still had to reinstall fibers:

```
git clone https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-codelabs
cd material-components-web-codelabs/mdc-101/starter
npm uninstall fibers
npm install fibers
npm install
npm start
```

Then the webpack server finally started.

Answer (score 0):

There's a note on the node-fibers front page README about this. Fibers will not be supported on nodejs v16.x or higher.
https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/451
https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers

Comment: I was faced with the same issue and opted to use Node v14, it still doesn't work :/